# Universally quantified modus ponens in Coq

Tags: coq

I’m rather new to the Coq theorem prover. So I may very well have missed something fundamental when going through the tutorials.

Before I ask my question, let me assume some assumptions and recap *modus ponens*.

```
Coq < Parameter Antecedent : Prop .
Coq < Parameter Consequent : Prop .
Coq < Conjecture Minor : Antecedent .
Coq < Conjecture Major : Antecedent -> Consequent .
```

With these assumptions, modus ponens can be applied: a proof for the inferred `Consequent` can be constructed based on the `Minor` premisse and the `Major` premisse. Such a proof is simply the function application of `Major` with argument `Minor`.

```
Coq < Theorem ConsequentProof : Consequent . Proof . exact (Major Minor) . Qed .
```

That’s pretty neat.

So, now I wonder: *is such modus ponens inference possible in Coq with universally quantified propositions*?

In my example, I let the variable range over `nat`, but this is an arbitrary choice. Any `Set` (any combination of `Set`s?) (any `Type`?) will do.

```
Coq < Parameter FunctionAntecedent : nat -> Prop .
Coq < Parameter FunctionConsequent : nat -> Prop .
Coq < Conjecture QuantifiedMinor : forall n
           : nat, FunctionAntecedent n .
Coq < Conjecture QuantifiedMajor : forall n
           : nat, FunctionAntecedent n -> FunctionConsequent n .
```

Can I now proof `forall n : nat, FunctionConsequent n`?
My attempt does not work:

```
Coq < Theorem QuantifiedConsequentProof : forall n : nat, FunctionConsequent n .
QuantifiedConsequentProof < Proof .
QuantifiedConsequentProof < exact (forall n : nat,
                                        QuantifiedMajor n (QuantifiedMinor n)) .
QuantifiedConsequentProof < Abort .
```

This is the error output:

```
> exact (forall n : nat, QuantifiedMajor n (QuantifiedMinor n)) .
>                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: In environment
n : nat
The term "QuantifiedMajor n (QuantifiedMinor n)" has type
"FunctionConsequent n" which should be Set, Prop or Type.
```

My questions:

1. Is this `QuantifiedConsequent` provable? How, with which tactics?
2. Or do I need additional assumptions?
3. Also: what is the rationale for the type restriction (`Set`, `Prop` or `Type`, unquantified)? Are there any inconsistencies that could arise if Coq were more lenient?
4. Finally, as a catch-all question for any enlightening explanation: did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly, the trick is that `forall` is the wrong thing to use here, `forall` builds up a type abstracting over something, but the corresponding term is a function.

```
 Theorem fancy : forall (p q : nat -> Prop),
    (forall n, p n) -> (forall n, p n -> p q) -> (forall n, q n).
   exact (fun P Q pproof impl =>
              fun n => impl _ (pproof n)).
 Qed.
```

This can also just be solved with good old `auto`. And you can derive a Russels paradox-esque paradox if you don't stratify typing a little bit, if we allowed `Set : Set` instead of `Set : Type` then we'd have big issues.

The only thing you seem to be missing here is that `forall` is just the generalized version of `->`, to witness some universally quantified statement will be some lambda. The reason you avoided it before was due to the `Conjecture`'s instead of having everything inside of one term.

Comment: Thank you, jozefg. In general, I quite *like* your idea of “unlifting” the premisses (assumed conjectures) and turning them into additional antecedents in the theorem; and then proving that. But in this question, that wasn’t what I was trying to accomplish; and that approach did not help me figure out what I was doing wrong. Still I figured it out. The `forall`/`fun` distinction turned out to be key.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, jozefg. I figured it out.

The tactic that I needed to use is `intro`.

```
Coq < Theorem QuantifiedConsequentProof : forall n : nat, FunctionConsequent n .
QuantifiedConsequentProof < Proof .
QuantifiedConsequentProof < intro .
QuantifiedConsequentProof < exact (QuantifiedMajor n (QuantifiedMinor n)) .
QuantifiedConsequentProof < Qed .
```

The tactic `intro` lifts the universally quantified variable from the proposition to the working hypotheses.

Using

```
Coq < Print QuantifiedConsequentProof .
```

I can then see this constructed proof, from which I can deduce the alternative `exact` way to define it:

```
Coq < Theorem QuantifiedConsequentProof : forall n : nat, FunctionConsequent n .
QuantifiedConsequentProof < Proof .
QuantifiedConsequentProof < exact (fun n : nat =>
                                        QuantifiedMajor n (QuantifiedMinor n)) .
QuantifiedConsequentProof < Qed .
```

So, basically my mistake was that the proof is supposed to be a function, not a `forall`-expression. The *type* of the proof is a `forall`-proposition, but the proof itself is a function.

Actually, the more I think about it, the more it makes sense: this proof, being a function, can in turn be applied to an argument, resulting in a new proof. When applied to an expression that has type `nat`, this results in the proof of the instantiated theorem.